# how do you retain quality of a swf when uploading into the internet?

Tags: adobe, flash, loss

When I open a swf file with adobe flash player 10.1 r52, it has the quality I want. But when I  drag and drop it into the google browser. There's a little distortion in my swf.

I want to know why this is?